# ejs string variable with space is not displayed properly

Tags: html, string, node.js, ejs

I am trying to display the search query in the search bar in HTML.
But if the variable includes a space, the webpage is only going to display the first word.

Here is the code

```
app.get('/search', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.originalUrl,'oro')
    console.log(req.query['search_query'],'aaaaaaa')
    res.render('search.ejs', {
        user : req.user, 
        query : req.query['search_query']
    });
});
```

Here is the html code

```
<form action="/search" method="get">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" value = "search" style = "float: right"/>
        <div style="overflow: hidden; padding-right: .5em;">
        <input type="text" value = <%= query %> class="form-control" name="search_query" style = "width:100%;"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

query is the variable collected from the last webpage and passed to /search.

If I type in "I want to find xx", the webpage will only display "I" in the search box. However, in the console, the printout result is the full query " I want to find xx". The corresponding url is also correct "/search?search_query=I+want+to+find+xx".

Anyone has an idea? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Let's start with correcting your HTML, by using quotes in value:

```
<input type="text" value = "<%= query %>" class="form-control" name="search_query" style = "width:100%;"/>
```

Here under IE you should see a large error, on FF and Chrome browser will try to save the situation and catch only the first word.

Prolably rest of your words are used as attributes and ignored in this input.

Answer (score 1):

Change `<%= query %>` to `<%- query %>` .

Answer (score 1):

> To add a new line or space while working with ejs, you will have to replace string parameters with HTML tags.
>
> For example, here, I am replacing \n => < br/> to add a new line

`<% var testVar = 'Line1\nLine2' %> <%- testVar.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>') %>`

Answer (score 0):

Change <%= query %> to <%- query.replace(/ /g, " ") %>

I struggled for hours to render text with spaces

Answer (score 0):

Adding quotes seems to be the easiest solution to this

```
value = "<%= query %>"
```

Comment: your answer same like @beri

Answer (score 0):

to solve partial content change:

- <%= to <%-
- use: `` with "" inside

[image]

JS example:

```js
let txt = "some text"
console.log(`"${txt}"`)
```